# Can I delete media directories left over from an unused non-composer installed module in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, media-images

I have been trying to clear space on my server (every little bit helps).  I recently installed the FishPig extension and had no use for the Magefan_Blog module that was installed in my Magento 2 store.

I'm not exactly sure if Magefan_Blog comes with Magento 2.1.2 out of the box.  However, I didn't need it.  I tried uninstalling through CLI (command line), but I was only able to disable through command line with the `magento module:disable` command.

I then proceeded to delete the module and necessary table entries in the db, however I noticed that there were some files in `media/magefan_blog/b/l/` that were no longer being used.  There were only about 6, but like I said, I want to to clean everything.

Those image DID NOT show up when I installed the Shreeji Unusedimages extension, so it left me wondering, (if the Shreeji extension actually found unused images outside of the catalog) whether or not these images were still attached to something somewhere that could break my store in anyway.

Does anyone know if these images can be deleted without consequence?  Again, I have already removed the Magefan_Blog module from my Magento install.

In addition, can I also deleted the images from the directory "downloadable" as I've already deleted all the product entries for the sample data?

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure they're not used then Yes. However if you're still an it nervous use this command

```
 mv media/magefan_blog/ /home/#user#/magefan_blog/
```

Obviously replace ##user## with your user or replace the directory sending the folder to with root if you're logged in as root. Then test your site and look for any issues after the images are no longer available.

If all looks good, then delete the folder out your home folder

Comment: TImothy, do you know how to search the DB for pages that link to these "unused" items, or links to the items in general?  i was told that as long as there are no links in the DB, it is 100% safe to delete these items.  But, if there are still links to the files in the DB, it will throw errors somewhere down the line.

Comment: @Jason good question, try running this command `mysqldump --compact --skip-extended-insert -u root -proot mydb | grep "filename"` obviously change the user if required. If you have a recent db backup lying about you can run it against that rather than having the mysqldump

Comment: Timothy, thanks.  I'm not versed on sql, could you tell me what this query is going to do the database?  Sorry for asking more.

Comment: Mysqldump -u root -p --compact --skip-extended-insert -proot dbname | grep "name of media file"

Comment: I was actually looking for an explanation of the commands in the query line so others, including myself don't run the query without knowing exactly what it does.  I'll check the commands and post for myself and others.

Comment: It copies the database to a file (exports) and searches the output for the file name